# Java Treeset: "Cannot Resolve Constructor" for Comparator

Tags: java, constructor, integer, comparator, treeset

For some reason my comparator is not being accepted by my treeset. Help please?

Treeset class:

```
public class PQTreeQueue<Integer> extends AbstractQueue<Integer>{

private TreeSet<Integer> _pqTree;

public PQTreeQueue() {
    noZeroComparator noZero = new noZeroComparator();
    _pqTree = new TreeSet<Integer>(noZero);
}
```

Comparator class (defined in another file)

```
public class noZeroComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

@Override
public int compare(Integer e0, Integer e1) {
    if (e0.compareTo(e1) >= 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: a comparator that never returns 0 is not a valid comparator.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish by writing a comparator that never returns 0, but it will cause problems.

Comment: I added a note to my answer explaining why this isn't a valid comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `TreeSet` with generic parameter as Integer. The `TreeSet` constructor you specified need `comparator` whose generic parameter is either super type of Integer or Integer itself.
Definition of that constructor :-

```
TreeSet<E>(comparator<? super E>);
```

So better you don't pass Integer as generic parameter to `TreeSet`. Create your own class like `Integer` and then create `comparator` with generic parameter as your own class to that `comparator`, and same class as generic parameter to your custom integer class.

```
public class MyInterger {
    int value = 0;

      public int compareTo(MyInterger anotherInteger) {
            return compare(this.value, anotherInteger.value);
        }

      public static int compare(int x, int y) {
            return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
        }
}


public class noZeroComparator implements Comparator<MyInterger> {

@Override
public int compare(MyInterger e0, MyInterger e1) {
    if (e0.compareTo(e1) >= 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

}



public class PQTreeQueue<MyInterger> extends AbstractQueue<MyInterger>{

private TreeSet<MyInterger> _pqTree;

public PQTreeQueue() {

    noZeroComparator noZero = new noZeroComparator();
    _pqTree = new TreeSet<MyInterger>(noZero);
}
```

Comment: Why so? User want to have custom comparison, he/she don't want to return 0, just -1 or 1. Can your code achieve this?

Comment: 1) You mis-diagnosed the problem.  There is nothing wrong with using a `Comparator<Integer>` where a `Comparator<? super Integer>` is expected, as long as `Integer` hasn't been accidentally redefined the way it was in the question. 2) You repeated the OP's mistake of defining `PQTreeQueue` with an incorrect type parameter.

Comment: I added info to my answer explaining why it's wrong to write a comparator that only returns -1 or 1.

Comment: Giving wrong type parameter to PQTreeQueue is accepted. And my answer does not say that he should not use comparator<Integer>, I did mention: "generic parameter is either super type of Integer or Integer itself" in my answer. 
But the user might need some custom comparison for his/her {PQTreeQueue} where he don't want to return 0(may be he/she dont want equal items to be included in the tree which would not be included if comparator returns 0) in that case he/she can not rely on: what standard integer compare method should do.

Comment: The type parameter is "accepted", but it is not right.  The parameter _hides_ types of the same name.  In your example, `PQTreeQueue<MyInterger>` causes the other `MyInterger` to be hidden, so that it cannot be used in your class.  Uses of `MyInterger` in your class do _not_ refer to the type you declared above.  That clearly is not what is intended.

Comment: Regarding comparators, the comparator is defined by the javadoc as needing to have certain properties.  For all you know, the code in the runtime may be relying on those properties.  If you give it a comparator that doesn't follow the requirements, the runtime code may stop working.  I've seen `sort()` (Timsort) throw exceptions when it runs into an unexpected situation when a comparator doesn't meet the requirements.  Bottom line: if the javadoc says your implementation must do something, do it--don't try think up reasons why it's OK to violate the rules.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
public class PQTreeQueue<Integer> extends AbstractQueue<Integer>
```

This (the first part) is the syntax for declaring a generic class.  When you declare a generic class, the identifier in angle brackets is a *type parameter*.  It's just like the declaration in Java

```
public class ArrayList<E> ...
```

except that you called your type parameter `Integer` instead of `E`.  The compiler treats `Integer` the same way it treats `E`, though--it becomes a type parameter that can be replaced with any actual type, and the fact that the name `Integer` is used for other things in Java is meaningless.  The generic type loses all connection with `Integer`.  And everywhere else inside this class, `Integer` will refer to the type variable, not to the actual `java.lang.Integer`.

If you remove `<Integer>`:

```
public class PQTreeQueue extends AbstractQueue<Integer>
```

everything should work.  (Aside from the fact that a comparator that never returns 0 won't work.  What would happen if you call `compare(x, x)`?  Is it going to say that `x > x`?)

**MORE** info on the requirements for comparators: The mathematical rules are that a comparator imposes a total ordering, which means that the function must obey the rules for a total ordering (including transitivity).  According to [the javadoc for compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), "The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all x and y."  This means, in particular, that `sgn(compare(x,x)) == -sgn(compare(x,x))`, and this is possible only if `compare(x,x) == 0`.  This proves that a comparator that never returns 0 violates the rules, since `compare` must return 0 when both arguments are `==`.  [The rule is weaker with regard to arguments that are not `==` but are equal according to `.equals()`; the javadoc doesn't say you mustn't do it, but it does say that it could cause things like sorted sets and maps to behave strangely.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.]